# Azure powershell deployment - credentials management and expiration

Tags: powershell, azure, continuous-integration, webdeploy

I am automating deployment of a solution to Azure for CI purposes in powershell. I will be using WebDeploy to deploy websites and webjobs. I plan to create the CI user in Azure AD once for all environments, attach him to the subscription, download appropriate publishprofile file and put this file in the repository. Then use `Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile` while deployment is running on CI. Is this the optimal way to do it? Can I assume that the credentials stored in this file won't expire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the .publishsettings file mechanism is no longer been worked on, you should [create an Azure Active Directory Service Principal](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-authenticate-service-principal/) to grant access for your CI environment to Azure.

Answer (score 0):

Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile is using a `.publishsettings` file that has been downloaded using the `Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile`. This command will create a certificate in your subscription.

1. You can login the [Azure Classic Portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com/).
2. Click **Settings** > **Management certificates**, and search with the downloaded `.publishsettings` file name.

   [image]

You will be able to get the expire date of the certificate. It's usually one year long. I am not sure if it's long enough for you.

If your need a longer term, I suggest you to upload your own certificate, and use certificate instead. For more information, see [Upload an Azure Management API Management Certificate](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/azure-api-management-certs/)

For more detail about how to use the uploaded certificates, see [Getting Started with Azure PowerShell Cmdlets–Subscription Management](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cindygross/archive/2014/04/19/getting-started-with-azure-powershell-cmdlets-subscription-management.aspx)

Comment: Thx. The approach with dedicated service principal by @sascha-dittmann better fits to my scenario.